# How to get direct link of an image that contain hash using rails 4 and haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, haml

so i'm trying to put a direct link of an image in my %met tags, something like this:

```
%meta{ property: "og:image", content: "#{root_url.chomp('/')}#{asset_path('fb-article.png')}" }
```

and with this code i have this url in "content:" http://www.website.com/my-project/assets/fb-article.png

but all the images in project have an hash after deploy, like this:

```
fb-article-1b180e05b516c1fb2b80d5b6c055a32a.png
```

how can i put the url of this image im %meta content: ''?

Answer (score 0):

You should set assets digest to **false** on production.rb file and precompile assets.

```
config.assets.digest = false
```

Comment: but i need to maintain true the assets.digest, i'm trying to use the public folder but /fb-article.png don't works, if i put the image in /public/assets/fb-article.png, when have next deploy the image is deleted

Comment: You are right. please don't put image in /public/assets. it should automatic. If you set config.assets.digest = true and run rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production it will generate a digest and append to your file. Example: application-f1a14051f17824976271b9c0460232f0.css

Comment: nice, assets:precompile helps a lot, but how I refer to this image that contains now a hash? i need to put the url of image in

%meta{ property: "og:image", content: "path/to/image/fb-article.png')}" }

Comment: I know you use this for facebook share. you should use absolute:%meta{ property: "og:image", content: "yourdomain/path/to/image/fb-article.png')}" }